# Why is elmah.axd redirecting to /Account/Logon?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, logging, elmah

As near as I can tell, I've got elmah configured properly, according to the instructions at http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs

However, when I try to access elmah.axd in a browser, MVC redirects page to /Account/LogOn (which doesn't exist in my projects). As far as I can tell, there aren't any references to this controller or method in my project...

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that forms authentication is causing the redirection.

There are two solutions :

1) Disable forms authentication in IIS

Or

2) Add the following to web.config

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the standard location of the login action when you activate forms authentication. It looks that you have done this globally to all parts of the site meaning that a user needs to be authenticated in order to access it. You might have registered a global authorize filter or you have simply [configured elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages) to require authentication in order to be accessible.

Comment: Just did a CTRL+F on "Account/Login" and found out my cookie authentication in `Startup.Auth.cs` uses `LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")`.

Comment: I ran into similar issue, I have enabled authentication, once I am authenticated I am still unable to browse to elmah path and view the logs, browsing to elmah path redirects to login page, even though I am currently logged in

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Forms authenticaton you have set up in your site, which is probably configured to block most pages. You need to whitelist elmah.axd (add a <location> to web.config), or add a login logic as this data shouldn't be publicly available anyway.

Also, use nuget to add Elmah, much easier.